# Gitlab CI for Spring Boot Maven stuck

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gitlab-ci

I have a spring boot application with the following ci pipeline on my self hosted gitlab:

```
 stages:
  - build

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
```

pomfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Start of this week from one day to another it stopped working and stucks at `Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.6.3/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.6.3.pom`

Did they change the Rate limits so I run into a soft ban from maven repo now?

Comment: Sometimes there are issues related accessibility of the central repository in GitHub actions ...observed them as well several times..

Comment: I noticed some failing pipelines in the past but all of them succeeded on the first retry...
Im just concerned that this is now happening for 5 days in a row.

Comment: Is that on Github or corporate GitHub enterprise?

Comment: Self hosted Gitlab;

Comment: Than your should check your networks...GitLab CI .. node connection to central... if you host your own why don't you use a repository manager ... that would prevent such things..and would make it more faster...

Comment: It contains about 15 projects mainly php with lftp pipelines this is my first try to maven ci; never thought about caching

Comment: I strongly recommend to install a repository manager makes life easier...also for other things (php has a package manager as well as far as I know ...can be handled by repo manager as well...)...